# Is there a way to change the significance level (alpha) in R?

Tags: r, statistics, hypothesis-test, significance

Im trying to perform a simple hypothesis test but now I need t-values for alpha = 0.01 instead of 0.05 (the default). Is there a way to do this in R?

This is what I am trying to get for alpha = 0.01:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMqYE.png)

Comment: can you please include the information from your image in a text format (e.g. in a code chunk) instead? Images are unsearchable and inaccessible ...

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `t.test` function in R, you can use the argument `conf.level = 0.99`, since the confidence level is equivalent to 1 – the alpha level. [You can also read this page on Rdocumentation on the t.test function for more information on what arguments can be used](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test)

Comment: note that the only thing this will change is the confidence interval calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a statistical question rather than a programming question, and as such probably belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Results table:

```r
            Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 93.10386  44.482243  2.093057 3.647203e-02
       educ 39.82828   3.314467 12.016497 3.783286e-32
```

When you change alpha (the cutoff value for significance testing), **nothing in the table above — neither the t-statistic (`t value`) nor the p-value (`Pr(>|t|)`) — changes**. The only thing that changes is the judgment of whether you rejected or failed to reject the null hypothesis. In this case, since the p-value for the intercept (0.036) is between 0.01 and 0.05, the conclusion would change from "reject H0" (alpha=0.05) to "fail to reject H0" (alpha=0.01). The p-value for `educ` is *way* less than 0.01, so the conclusion would be "reject" either way.

In most cases, base-R functions don't specify an alpha value; they let you make the decision yourself.  If you do have a vector of p-values, you could implement an alpha threshold by saying

```r
result <- ifelse(pval<alpha, "reject H0", "fail to reject H0")
```